# Forum style order with LINQ

Tags: linq, sorting

I've created a simple forum in Umbraco using page nodes as threads with the child pages acting as replies. I'd like to sort  the most recent activities by to latest created or latest replied, like any forum does it. I'm really terrible at LINQ and was hoping you could help me out with the syntax. This is about as far as I've gotten (ordering the first level) but I'm not sure how to include the child pages of each child of CurrentPage in it. Any input to help me along the way?

```
    var childPages = CurrentPage.Children.OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate);
```

Comment: It's not really clear, what do you want to order?

Comment: Actually just the child nodes of the current page but if one of the child nodes of those child nodes has a CreatedDate that is more current than one of the child nodes of the current page I want that node to list higher up. It's really hard to explain...

Say that you have three page nodes and they are created June 1st, 3rd and 5th. If I just order those in "forum kind of way" it would be 5th, 3rd, 1st. But if the "3rd" one has a child node (reply) created June 9th I'd want the order to be 3rd, 5th, 1st.